# Loop JSON by variable in Postman

Tags: arrays, json, rest, api, postman

I have a JSON response stored in a variable 
`savedData = {"ID":"{{ID}}","command":"ok"}`. Also created an array variable 
`ID = [1,2,3]`. I want to loop the JSON based on the array variable and apply the variable in the body in postman.

**Example**

`{"ID":"1","command":"ok"},{"ID":"2","command":"ok"},{"ID":"3","command":"ok"}`

I am new to postman and would appreciate your support.

Comment: what do you mean by loop the json ?

Comment: JSON should be multiplied based on the no values in variable ID as shown in example

Comment: the output is an multiplied array right ? array of objects ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, the question is lacking detail and context - Are you setting the environment variable manually? How are you going to loop through that in a single request? Is the request body the same each time, apart from the ID? Can you not just use a data file and the runner to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
let savedData = {"ID":[1,2,3],"command":"ok"};
let output = [];
savedData['ID'].map(function (item, index) {
     let temp={};
     temp['ID'] = item;
     temp['comman'] = 'ok';
     output.push(temp)
});
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But I need the values in the variable. In the example 1,2,3 was a sample. I may have non numerical chars as well.

Comment: I am trying to call an environmental variable instead on constant values for ID but getting error. let savedData = {"ID":pm.variables.get("ID"),"command":"ok"};

Comment: Also what if my json is like this {{"ID":[1,2,3],"command":"ok"},{"comnd":"ok"}}